# Provide sign-in credentials to Play Console "Pre-launch report" for Jetpack Compose view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, google-play-console, prelaunch

I can see that 'Play Console' expects *"old"* `android.view.View` IDs to be passed in for "username/password resource ID" fields:

[image]

I'm not able to figure out how to provide resource ID for Jetpack Compose view hierarchy. I suspect that it should somehow be connected with [`Semantics`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/package-summary), but I'm not sure if Play Console supports Jetpack Compose view.

Curious if anybody has been able to set this up.

Comment: Stack overflow is a bad place to get the attention of any particular development team. It should be reported to the product team bug tracker, in this case in [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) - look for existing problems matching your case first and put a star if you find one - otherwise create a new issue.

Comment: On current version of developer console ids are optional.

Comment: we're in progress trying without providing the resource id for both username & password, hopefully it works for the pre-launch report, will update it as well in here

Comment: To add to @PhilDukhov 's comment. This appears to already be on the team's radar. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220801884